# can't pass arraylist through intent.putExtra

Tags: android, android-activity, arraylist

I am trying to pass an `ArrayList<driver>` to a new activity using intent.putExtra, but I'm getting this error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name =com.example.irinab.licenta3.CustomerAccount$driver);
```

driver is an inside class in my current activity that already implements Serializable, so I don't understand why I'm getting this error. 
Here's the code for driver class :

```
private class driver implements Serializable
    {
        private final String name;
        private final boolean available;

        driver(String nume, boolean av)
        {
            this.name = nume;
            this.available = av;
        }
    }
```

and here's the part of code for intent:

```
Intent startShowListIntent = new Intent(CustomerAccount.this,    ShowList.class);
startShowListIntent.putExtra("id",ID);
startShowListIntent.putExtra("type",type);
startShowListIntent.putExtra("drivers",online_drivers);
startActivity(startShowListIntent);
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use singleton class rather than passing through intents

Comment: this is not full exception I believe, can you search for `Caused by`?

Comment: I think in android it's better to make your class implement parcelable rather than serializable as the serilization involves lot more memory churn compared to parceling,then you can send the list by using the method  intent.putParcelableArrayList(key, value); here is a good tutorial on implementing parcellable:http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-parcelable-example-passing-data-between-activities/

Comment: @Irina make your class public and make sure it has public constructor and see if it helps

Comment: I think you should create getters and setters for your class too

Comment: You need to use Parcelable to send your arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

Android intents not supports to pass a serializable arraylist through. You should implement parcelable, because parcelable arraylist are supported.

Answer (score 0):

This is your MainActivity

```
ArrayList<Model> arrmodel = new ArrayList<Model>();
                Model m = new Model();
                Model n = new Model();
                arrmodel.add(m);
                arrmodel.add(n);

                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                for(int i = 0;i<arrmodel.size();i++){
                b.putSerializable("ss"+i, arrmodel.get(i));
                }
                b.putInt("size", arrmodel.size());
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("bundle", b);
                startActivity(intent);
```

This is your SecondActivity

```
 Bundle value=getIntent().getExtras().getBundle("bundle");
        ArrayList<Model> arrmodelArrayList = new ArrayList<Model>();
        for(int i = 0;i<value.getInt("size");i++){
            arrmodelArrayList.add((Model) value.getSerializable("ss"+i));
        }
```

But it is discouraged